# Why does the preprocessor distinguish between number and character tokens?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, token, c-preprocessor

According to the language specification, the lexical elements are defined like this:

```
token:
    keyword
    identifier

    constant

    string-literal
    operator
    punctuator

preprocessing-token:
    header-name
    identifier

    pp-number
    character-constant

    string-literal
    operator
    punctuator

    each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
```

Why is there a distinction between a number and a character on the preprocessing token level, whereas on the token level, there are only constants? I don't see the benefit in this distinction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names of the non-terminals in the C grammars are not normative; they simply exist for purpose of description. It is only important that the behaviour be correctly described. The grammar itself is not sufficient to describe the language; it needs to be read along with the text, which imposes further restrictions on well-formed programs.

There is not a one-to-one relationship between preprocessor tokens and program tokens. There is overlap: a preprocessor `identifier` might be a keywords or it might be one of the various definable symbol types (including some constants and `typedef-names`). A `pp-number` might be an integer or floating constant, but it might also be invalid. The lexical productions are not all mutually exclusive, and the actual application of lexical category to a substring of the program requires procedures described in the standard text, and not in the formal grammar.

Character constants pass directly from the preprocessor into the program syntax without modification (although they are then subsumed into the `constant` category). If there is a single comment about preprocessor numbers (such as the fact that they must be convertible into a real numeric constant literal if they survive the preprocessor) is a sufficient reason to have the category.

Also, what would it add to include `character-constant` in the definition of `pp-number`? You still need both productions in order to describe the language.

Comment: What would be an example of an invalid `pp-number`?

Comment: @fredoverflow: Some examples: 3q, 3.14159U, 019, 0y21, and my alltime favorite 0x7E+2 (which, unlike 0x7F+1, is a single token).

Comment: @FredOverflow: Another pp-number which cannot be assigned a value in translation phase 7 (as the standard says) is `192.168.0.1`. That is, however, a single preprocessor token (which makes a difference if you need to use the `##` operator with it.)

Comment: Indeed, the C++ standard says `The program fragment 1Ex is parsed as a preprocessing number token (one that is not a valid floating or integer literal token)`... so what happens to such a preprocessor token later on? Does it result in a compiler error, because it cannot be converted into a token? Then what exactly is the point of having preprocessor number tokens be a strict superset of the number tokens?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Either a preprocessing token is a valid token after preprocessing or the program is invalid (can't find if it's simply undefined or if a diagnostic is required atm), they're neither split into several tokens (`0x7E+2` is invalid, not re-parsed as `0x7E + 2`)  nor concatenated (given `#define MINUS -`, `MINUS-x` are two unary minus operators, not pre-decrement).

Comment: @FredOverflow: Stringize (#) will work on any sequence of tokens (although commas and parentheses are difficult to insert into macro arguments :-) ), but concatenate (##) insists on single tokens. See http://ideone.com/b4caYK.

Comment: @mafso: It's a constraint violation (6.4/2 "Each preprocessing token that is converted to a token shall have the lexical form of a keyword, an identifier, a constant, a string literal, or a punctuator.") so a diagnostic is required (5.1.1.3). It's possible that a pp token never gets converted to a token, though. It might be stringized or ignored (`#define IGNORE(x)` / `IGNORE($=>)` )